# location.href doesn't work properly in wkwebview

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview, location-href

I am receiving url from webview through `location.href`.
However, if `location.href` is called consecutively on one page, the last `location.href` is called and the first `location.href` is missing.
Both are called well on Android, but is there a reason for that only in iOS wkwebview?

Comment: Any code? both `WKWebView` and HTML codes.

Comment: ```webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)``` is not being called at all. So I tried debugging on the web code. On the code, each ```location.href``` is executed through a conditional statement, which satisfies both conditions. When i put a breakpoint in each conditional statement and run it, ```location.href``` is all executed, but usually when you run the app, only the last ```location.href``` is called.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.